# Store the result of a Select(multiple results) in a variable(to be use inside a in statement later)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, subquery

I am trying to store multiple results set from a select query to a variable,
I want to get every events contained in a week, I use a 'select like' from my event table under the criteria of the particular week. 
Want to store it as a variable that I can use inside a in part of where clause in another query to get the quantities of customers included per skills in a week.
I can't use a set, since I want to return multiple values, and in this, using a select, only return the last value.(I actually receive an error but my assumption is from previous reading on the subject)
The three things I am unsure of here :

1. how to set it up to be formatted to be included as an in later
2. how to store multiple values in my variable from the Select
3. formatting to use to achieve a coma separated string
   values(result between apostrophes)

My first query(declare/select) returns all result between apostrophes. I need to find a way to combine them and coma separate them and store it in my variable.
The second query works fine and return what I want if I manually enter coma separated values between apostrophes in my in value instead of the variable so that part is fine.

```
Declare @IDC varchar(500);
SELECT @IDC = (SELECT '''' + E.NO_EVENT + '''' FROM TEST_APP.dbo.EVENT E
WHERE E.NO_EVENT like '1819________')

SELECT COUNT(L.SKILL) as qty, L.SKILL FROM TEST.dbo.LEADS L
WHERE L.NO_Event in (@IDC)
group by L.SKILL
```

I've tried small variation to no avail and also did some research on the subject but apparently can only find a single results stored as variable.
Executing the above query returns me :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use table variable/temp table to store multiple values:

```
SELECT E.NO_EVENT 
INTO #temp
FROM TEST_APP.dbo.EVENT E
WHERE E.NO_EVENT like '1819________'
```

---

If you are using SQL Server 2017 you could use `STRING_AGG/STRING_SPLIT`:

```
Declare @IDC varchar(500);
SELECT @IDC = (SELECT STRING_AGG(E.NO_EVENT, ',') 
               FROM TEST_APP.dbo.EVENT E
               WHERE E.NO_EVENT like '1819________');
```

and then:

```
SELECT COUNT(L.SKILL) as qty, L.SKILL FROM TEST.dbo.LEADS L
WHERE L.NO_Event in (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@IDC, ',') s)
group by L.SKILL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is exactly what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 0):

Create a table variable and then insert to it like this:

```
declare @table table (col1 int, col2 varchar(max))...
insert @table 
select...
```